# Why is react native blocking notifications on android?

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, android-notifications

I am using notifee to create notifications in a react native app. I noticed, by default notifications get blocked by android (See under Settings->Apps->My App). Do I have to set the permission somewhere in my app?

When I enable notifications in the Apps-Settings, they work fine, but I'd like them to be enabled when installing the apk.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, You have to explicitly request notifications permission if you targets Android 13.

Paste the following line in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATION"/>
```

And then in your app:

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native' 

const requestNotificationPermission = async () => {
try {
  await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.POST_NOTIFICATION
  )
} catch (err) {
  if (_DEV_) console.warn('requestNotificationPermission error: ', err)
 }
}
```

Permission could be named "POST_NOTIFICATION" or "POST_NOTIFICATIONS", depending on your RN version.

Comment: I belive this doesn't work with react native v 0.68.2. Is there another way or do is updating react-native the only way? I checked the docs and I can't find a permission for the notifications in the docs for that version.

Comment: I've just created a fresh RN project with version 0.68.2 and I can see  POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission in PermissionsAndroid.

Comment: For me I can't ise them... They aren't listed in the docs either: https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.68/permissionsandroid

Comment: When I console.log PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS it's not there aswell

Comment: This worked for me on react native 0.70.4 when the Notifee suggestion did not.

Comment: Worked for me with RN v0.70.5 

Comment: For me it was `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` and not `POST_NOTIFICATION` ! so if you get "Permission is null" error this is probably why. At first I missed that last comment by Armin

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to request notification permission explicitly in android, even `POST_NOTIFICATION` is also deprecated,
In android by default notification is enabled, until & unless you turnoff forcefully, for a simple solution,
as you are using notifee, I will recommend using
requestPermission function inside your parent/App.js component

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      // ask for notification permission
      await notifee.requestPermission();
    })();

    return () => {
      // this now gets called when the component unmounts
    };
  }, []);
```